# Accepted data types for wps process JTS:difference in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, wps

I am trying to use JTS:difference (present as wps service on GeoServer) using OpenLayers API.
In OpenLayers wps-client example,  I have replaced intersection with difference and 
I get illegal argument exception.
Can someone please help on what is valid for a: and b: for JTS:difference process?

```
var map, client, intersect, buffer;

function init() {

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        allOverlays: true,
        center: [114, 16],
        zoom: 4,
        layers: [new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector()]
    });

    var features = [new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT(
        'LINESTRING(117 22,112 18,118 13, 115 8)'
    ))];
    var geometry = OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT(
        'POLYGON((110 20,120 20,120 10,110 10,110 20),(112 17,118 18,118 16,112 15,112 17))'
    );

    map.baseLayer.addFeatures(features);
    map.baseLayer.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry)]);

    client = new OpenLayers.WPSClient({
        servers: {
            opengeo: 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wps'
        }
    });

    // Create a process and configure it
    intersect = client.getProcess('opengeo', 'JTS:intersection');    
    intersect.configure({
        // spatial input can be a feature or a geometry or an array of
        // features or geometries
        inputs: {
            a: features,
            b: geometry
        }
    });

    // Create another process which chains the previous one and execute it
    buffer = client.getProcess('opengeo', 'JTS:buffer');
    buffer.execute({
        inputs: {
            geom: intersect.output(),
            distance: 1
        },
        success: function(outputs) {
            // outputs.result is a feature or an array of features for spatial
            // processes.
            map.baseLayer.addFeatures(outputs.result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: By looking at the javadoc in http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/javadoc/ all geometries should be accepted, despite GeometryCollections: `TopologyException - if a robustness error occurs 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - if either input is a non-empty GeometryCollection`

Comment: @PolyGeo  - is there anything wrong in the above code ? could you please try by replacing intersection with difference...and tell if you get error..?

Comment: Sorry - this is not a question that I can assist with technically.

Comment: PolyGeo I misunderstood your first comment. You meant 'except' in place of 'despite'?. Anyway I know now that GeometryCollections cannot be given as input to JTS:difference. So the code above will not work.